# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \prod_{k=1}^{n} f(k)$ diverges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, real-numbers

How can I prove the divergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \prod_{k=1}^{n} f(k)\right) $$

if $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is injective? $     $

Comment: What is the limit of the general term, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n f(k)$?  Is it zero?

Comment: You need parentheses on that factorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is injective
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} f(k)\geqslant n!$$
And
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1!} \prod_{k=1}^{n} f(k)\right)\geqslant \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n+1}\to\infty
$$

Comment: Thank you! it solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: For each $n$, the $n$th term is at least $1/n$. Can you see why?